# How to check if property is an object with property "__deferred"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out if a property has only 1 object with property "__deferred",

Here is how it looks like in chrome developer tools,

[image]

**Update to make it clear**

I might have dynamic objects, what I really want is

if(property.Object.hasOnlyProperty == '__deferred') <-- I know this doesn't work, but I want something similar..

***I don't want property to be added to my expandedChildResults array if it is a object like in the picture, exactly same.***

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty('property')`

Comment: you only need `property.hasOwnProperty("__deferred")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about non-enumerable properties and properties inherited from prototype (see [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)), you can used [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
function isPropertyAnObjectWithJustSingle__deferred(property) {
    var keys;
    return typeof property === 'object' && // test if it's and object
        (keys = Object.keys(property)).length === 1 && // test if it has just sibgle property
        keys[0] === '__deferred'; // test if that property is '__deferred'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the [hasOwnProperty("propertyName")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method should be able to tell you if the `__deferred`  exists in the object